# Paypal IPN read variables - transaction[0].amount

Tags: php, post, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using Paypal Adaptive Payments and I'm trying to read parameters from my IPN listener, but is not very simple. First of all this is my IPN listener:

```
<?php
/**
 * This is a sample implementation of an IPN listener
 * that uses the SDK's PPIPNMessage class to process IPNs
 * 
 * This sample simply validates the incoming IPN message
 * and logs IPN variables. In a real application, you will
 * validate the IPN and initiate some action based on the 
 * incoming IPN variables.
 */
require_once("paypal/samples/PPBootStrap.php");

$ipnMessage = new PPIPNMessage();
foreach($ipnMessage->getRawData() as $key => $value) {
    error_log("IPN: $key => $value");
}


if($ipnMessage->validate()) {
    error_log("Success: Got valid IPN data");   




    $receiver_email = $_POST['transaction[0].amount']; //DOES NOT WORK

        //THIS TWO PARAMETERS ARE OK

    $payment_status = $_POST['status'];
    $sender_email = $_POST['sender_email'];


} else {
    error_log("Error: Got invalid IPN data");   
}

?>
```

status and sender_email are correctly read, but that strange transaction[0].amount returns undefined index error! I know that was passed as transaction%5B0%5D.amount but even trying to substitute the string returns the same error!

Answer (score 0):

PHP has issues with array data, see https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/blob/master/lib/ipn/PPIPNMessage.php#L45. Please use urldecode to decode data accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix it in PPIPNMessage class in __construct. Add urldecode for both params

```
$this->ipnData[urldecode($keyValue[0])] = urldecode($keyValue[1]);
```

It has been fixed in master branch, but not yet in the last release